# How to determine if a number is even or odd with AMPScript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a global variable called `@Count`. I also have a for loop that increases the `@Count` by 1 each time I cycle through the loop. Is there a way for me to detect with AMPScript whether `@Count` is an odd or even number?

```
%%[

/* SET GLOBAL COUNT VARIABLE */
SET @Count = 0

/* INCREASE THE COUNT BY 1 EACH TIME */
FOR @i = 1 TO @increaseCount DO
  SET @Count = Add(@Count,1)
NEXT @i

/* DO SOMETHING IF COUNT IS EVEN OR ODD NUMBER */
IF @Count == "even" THEN
  BLANK
ELSEIF  @Count == "odd" THEN
  BLANK
ENDIF

]%%
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd suggest using the [**MOD()**](https://ampscript.guide/book/mod) AMPScript function.  If `@sum` is evenly divisible by 2 then it's even, otherwise it's odd:

```
%%[

var @i, @sum, @max
set @sum = 0
set @max = 10

FOR @i = 1 TO @max DO
  SET @sum = Add(@sum,1)
NEXT @i

IF mod(@sum,2) == 0 THEN
  output(concat("<br>", @sum, " is even"))
ELSE
  output(concat("<br>", @sum, " is odd"))
ENDIF

]%%
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `MOD(@Count, 2) == 1`. Here is the [documentation](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#section_66) for the `MOD` function. If it's 0, you're even. If it's 1, you're odd.