# Is there a modulus operator in AMPscript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, math

I'm looking for modulus operator in their [docs](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/) but I can't find it so I though I would ask here. I have a loop written in AMPscript and I need to insert a piece of html every X item. Is there a modulus operator in AMPscript?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#mod)?

Comment: Here's an example with some code: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/112318/5202

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Mod](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/) function is documented in the [Utilities AMPscript Functions](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/) page, so it takes a moment to find. Like most Mod functions, it takes the dividend and the divisor as the two parameters and returns the remainder.